# what parsing means?

Tags: language-agnostic

what parsing means for web development. Things like parsing html, parsing style sheets etc are used. Also web development languages use parse methods. What is essence parsing means here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, parsing means inspecting a text string, character by character, and performing certain actions based on the meaning inherent in those characters.

A web browser parses HTML to translate it into blocks of content on the page. It parses style sheets to apply/adjust the styles of those blocks.

Answer (score 2):

By [Definition](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=en:en+parse&qscrl=1):

> Verb: Analyze (a sentence) into its
> component parts and describe their
> syntactic roles.
>
> Noun: An act of or
> the result obtained by parsing a
> string or a text

Its not specific to web development. Parsing just would mean computing and crunching stuff. Like a web browser **parses** HTML and displays a web page.